# Why won't my delete item event emit to the parent?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, eventemitter

I am trying to delete an item from my data attribute. A delete is triggered by the delete button on each item. That they triggers the deleteItem(index) function in the child component, which then emits to the parent. But for some reason it never triggers the event handler in the parent.

Help with the drag n drop would be a plus as well. Thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/4Ld0ubjt/

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>

    </title>

    <!--- Import Vue.js library --->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div id="itemsApp" @delete-item="deleteItem(idx)">
            <list-item v-for="(item, index) in items" v-bind:index="index" v-bind:item="item"></list-item>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
<!--- END: Main body --->
```

```js
/**
    * Function to run after the Document has completed loading.
    */
$(function () {

    /**
    * Load and initialize the Module Object
    */
    Vue.component('list-item', {
        props: ['item', 'index'],
        template: `
            <div draggable="true" @dragStart="dragstart(index, $event)" @dragFinish="dragfinsih(index, $event)" class="bookmark list-group-item clearfix" :id="index">
                <span class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger pull-left" title="Move Bookmark"></span>
                <a :href="item.URL_TE" :id="item.URL_HSH_NR">{{item.URL_NA}} - {{index}}</a>
                <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                    <a class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit" role="button" title="Edit Bookmark" href="##"></a>
                    <button v-on:click="deleteItem(index)" class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove delete" title="Delete Bookmark"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        `,
        methods: {
            deleteItem(idx) {
                console.log("Index? " + idx);
                this.$emit('delete-item', idx);
            },
            /**********START DRAG AND DROP LOGIC********** */
            dragstart(which, ev) {
                console.log("In dragStart " + JSON.stringify(ev));
                ev.dataTransfer.setData('Text', which.index);
                ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move'
                this.dragging = which;
            },
            dragfinish(to, ev) {
                this.moveItem(this.dragging, to);
            },
            moveItem(from, to) {
                this.bookmarks.splice(to, 0, this.bookmarks.splice(from, 1)[0]);
            }
            /**********END DRAG AND DROP LOGIC********** */
        },
    })


    var itemsApp = new Vue({
        el: '#itemsApp',
        data: {
            items: [
                {
                    "URL_NA": "Some text",
                    "URL_HSH_NR": 558493829494,
                    "URL_TE": "SOME MORE TEXT"
                },
                {
                    "URL_NA": "Some text",
                    "URL_HSH_NR": 558493829494,
                    "URL_TE": "SOME MORE TEXT"
                }
            ]
        },
        methods: {
            deleteItem(i) {
                console.log("In parent deleteItem " + i);
                this.data.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event handler should be on child component

```
  <div id="itemsApp">
            <list-item v-for="(item, index) in items" v-bind:index="index" v-bind:item="item" @delete-item="deleteItem"></list-item>
        </div>
```

In Vue component, `data` should be a function

```
 var itemsApp = new Vue({
        el: '#itemsApp',
        data() {
           return {
            items: [
                {
                    "URL_NA": "Some text",
                    "URL_HSH_NR": 558493829494,
                    "URL_TE": "SOME MORE TEXT"
                },
                {
                    "URL_NA": "Some text",
                    "URL_HSH_NR": 558493829494,
                    "URL_TE": "SOME MORE TEXT"
                }
            ]
           }
        },
        methods: {
            deleteItem(i) {
                console.log("In parent deleteItem " + i);
                this.items.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    })
```

You can check [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/ittus/vz15beqm/5/)

Comment: Oh dang. I thought it was supposed to be on the parent and that the event handler on the button in the child component would then pass it up to an event handler on the parent. Can you explain the logic of that for me? To me it seems that with it being on the child, it would call the function within the child, not the parent.

Comment: `<list-item />` is in parent template. So if you call `this.$emit('delete-item', idx);`, it will emit to `@delete-item` in parent template.